# Puppeteer does not get element by absolute XPath while google tools does

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I need to get to a button but I need to get it by absolute XPath because on each reload the id of that button changes.
So when I try to get the button with xPath in dev tools I get the next result:
[image]

**Which is the result that I need**

But when I try to do it in puppeteer with the next code:

```
const screeners = await page.$x(
  '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a[2]',
);console.log(screeners);
```

I get : `[]`

What may be the reason that dev tools gets the element but puppeteer doesnt?

Comment: something like https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforxpath/ helps?

Comment: Unfortunately I used the function, but with no progress it still gives me a empty array.

Comment: is it a website that you can include here. maybe someone else will be able to help

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the site. These absolute XPaths are generally a [bad idea](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors)--they're extremely specific, so if even a single div is different, the whole thing breaks. Much better to use an id, class or attribute.

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah I would always stick to those on the usual, but in that case the id and class are changing everytime on refresh, so it would not be clever to get an undefined element because the selector changed. Thanks for the tip tho

Comment: Well there's almost always something better. I've scraped hundreds of sites and have never had to resort to this. The full-sized XPath is about as bad as it could be possibly be. If you share the site I can almost guarantee a better, more stable selector than what you have here. Also, just because you can select something in DevTools offers no guarantee that it works in Puppeteer, due to blocking, visibility, shadow DOMs and frames. So even if the selector is correct, there's no telling what the problem might be without a [mcve].

Comment: In fact, I can see all sorts of stable-looking class names on that element. I'd use those, and/or a stable parent element class/id.